# I can't access the Context Provider in useContext hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I created a Context API for menu bar and it is my first time using it, and that also I am using it with typescript which i started learning few days ago.

**Context Creator and Provider Code in App.jsx**

```js
type MenuBar = {
  menu: boolean
  setMenu: any
}

function App() {
  const MenuBarContext = React.createContext<Partial<MenuBar>>({})
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState<boolean>(false)
  return (
    <MenuBarContext.Provider value={{ menu, setMenu }}>
      <div className="h-full font-primary-400">
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </MenuBarContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**Accesing using UseContext Hook in Navbar Component**

```js
const { menu, setMenu } = useContext(MenuBarContext)
```

I want to pass the state in the context API and access it in different components. But the accessing the context API using useContext hook gives error as -

`Cannot find name 'MenuBarContext'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the context in a separate file and import it where you need it.

MenuBarContext.ts:

```
import React from 'react';
// other imports...
const MenuBarContext = React.createContext<Partial<MenuBar>>({});
export default MenuBarContext;
```

Import it like so when you need to use `MenuBarContext.Provider` or `useContext(MenuBarContext)`:

```
import MenuBarContext from './MenuBarContext';
```